# No decode delegate for ImageMagick

Tags: linux, imagemagick

I am try to compress the JPEG file and installed ImageMagick on Linux machine. PFB.

[image]

Below is the convert command looks like.

[image]

Any idea to fix it?

Below are logs :

```
No package 'pango' found
configure:32506: result: 
configure:32565: result: -------------------------------------------------------------
configure:32569: checking for PNG
configure:32576: $PKG_CONFIG --exists --print-errors "libpng >= 1.0.0"
configure:32579: $? = 0
configure:32593: $PKG_CONFIG --exists --print-errors "libpng >= 1.0.0"
configure:32596: $? = 0
configure:32634: result: yes
configure:32638: result: 
configure:32682: result: -------------------------------------------------------------
configure:32686: checking for RAW_R
configure:32693: $PKG_CONFIG --exists --print-errors "libraw_r >= 0.14.8"
Package libraw_r was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `libraw_r.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'libraw_r' found
configure:32696: $? = 1
configure:32710: $PKG_CONFIG --exists --print-errors "libraw_r >= 0.14.8"
Package libraw_r was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `libraw_r.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'libraw_r' found
configure:32713: $? = 1
configure:32727: result: no
No package 'libraw_r' found
configure:32755: result: 
configure:33003: result: -------------------------------------------------------------
configure:33005: checking for TIFF
configure:33007: result: 
configure:33011: checking tiff.h usability
configure:33011: gcc -std=gnu99 -std=gnu99 -c -I/usr/include/libpng15        -fopenmp -g -O2 -Wall -mtune=corei7 -fexceptions -pthread -DMAGICKCORE_HDRI_ENABLE=0 -DMAGICKCORE_QUANTUM_DEPTH=16   -DMAGICKCORE_HDRI_ENABLE=0 -DMAGICKCORE_QUANTUM_DEPTH=16 conftest.c >&5
conftest.c:260:18: fatal error: tiff.h: No such file or directory
 #include <tiff.h>
                  ^
compilation terminated.
configure:33011: $? = 1
configure: failed program was:
```

Answer (score 0):

Compile it in.

```
./configure -with-png=yes \
       --with-jpeg=yes \
       --with-jp2=yes \
       --with-freetype=yes
```

From 
http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?t=22086.

Comment: You're missing some dependencies. Do yourself a favor and install from your distro's package manager instead, apt get install ImageMagick. Of course that only if you do have a package manager and you re not on an embedded device or something like that.

Comment: can we restrict `apt get install ImageMagick` to download only 6.9 version. I don't want to install the latest version.

Comment: Should be possible with sudo `apt install imagemagick=<version>`, or you could `apt install` the dependencies, then `./configure` your own - see https://gist.githubusercontent.com/rodleviton/74e22e952bd6e7e5bee1/raw/5330b14a6d64069c6d9880f76341313b1c3b39c6/imagemagick-install-steps

Comment: Followed these 2 steps `yum -y groupinstall 'Development Tools'
 yum -y install bzip2-devel freetype-devel libjpeg-devel libpng-devel libtiff-devel giflib-devel zlib-devel ghostscript-devel djvulibre-devel libwmf-devel jasper-devel libtool-ltdl-devel libX11-devel libXext-devel libXt-devel lcms-devel libxml2-devel librsvg2-devel OpenEXR-devel php-devel` from https://www.vultr.com/docs/install-imagemagick-on-centos-6/ and its worked.